# Android set contact's photo with ContactsContract

Tags: android, contactscontract

I am looking for a way to programatically update a contact's photo with a given Bitmap image. I'm doing the following, but nothing happens. Neither is the picture being set nor occurs an error.

```
Cursor cursor = provider.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE},
                ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE +"=?",
                new String[]{accountType},
                null);

        // Only one entry
        if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID));
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();

        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, Integer.parseInt(id))
                .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Photo.PHOTO, bytes)
                .build());
    }
    provider.applyBatch(ops);
```

The image get loaded from a REST api, what seems to work properly since the bytes object actually is of the size of the downloaded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code connects photo data row to the specific raw contact, but it doesn't initiate any procedures that will change display photo for that raw contact and corresponding contact.

Use [`ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.DisplayPhoto.html) for forced raw contact display photo editing. There is good usage example in the docs.